# Using Lua in Arduino project

Tags: lua

I want to write code for my Arduino in Lua. Where I can find the necessary (pins) I/O lib and examples for Arduino IDE?
UPD: I've got arduino mega with many memory.

Comment: You want to code in Lua? And have that code run on the Arduino? Which Arduino do you have in mind?

Comment: @NickGammon , that's true, I want to write program for arduino uno.

Comment: @NickGammon: ok, now I've got an arduino mega.

Comment: It looks like the ESP8266 runs Lua, but I haven't seen it running on an Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua is an interpreted language. That is, the compile phase turns Lua source code into intermediate "pseudo-code" which the Lua interpreter then runs. It doesn't compile into machine code, and therefore there is nothing that could be uploaded to your Uno as a "hex" file.

In any case, with only 2 KB of RAM, it wouldn't be very practical to attempt to run Lua on a Uno. I like Lua personally, but running it on the (AVR) Arduinos just isn't practical.

Comment: Lua is a language (a spec of syntax and semantics). Its most widespread implementation is an interpreter, but there is nothing in the Lua language that prevents one from writing a compiler that emits Arduino code (or any other code). I find it actually unexpected that no one has made it yet.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Arduino IDE supports C++ only. You can use other languages to communicate with Arduino from your PC. Take a look at Firmata.

Comment: An enterprising person might cross compile `Lau` to `C++` ... _Once upon a time_ our AT&T C++ compiler only emmitted C and the `cc` command turned that into object coed.